# how to separate 1 table into 2 tables and add a new column?

Tags: mysql

i have 1 table with i want to separate it into 2 tables and i want to add a new column to the new table. how can i do that?
example :
I have table A with column : a, b, c
and i want to copy the data into new table ( Table B and C )
table B with column : a, e,
table C with column : b, c, f

[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p2T4.png)

I've tried

CREATE TABLE C as SELECT A.b, A.c FROM A;

but i dont know how to add the new column (c and f). and if i already have hundreds of data what is the best way to input data into these new columns? should i do it one by one? im new to programing and sql, thank you for helping me.

Comment: This question is a little difficult to follow. You might make it clearer by using more explicit table names in your example rather than letters from the beginning of the alphabet which are also used for column names.

Or, use letters from the end of the alphabet for the table names to help increase clarity.

Answer (score 0):

to add new column, you need to use ALTER.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype;
```

Source: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) also it will be a good idea to read the entire thing for mysql. you will learn a lot

but as a warning. make sure you understand what you are doing, the column can be removed later on. but making mistakes can damage your data.

if you need to alter your tables for a specific task only then I suggest creating temporary tables that you can then do whatever you need with. and then discarding them